# Append html in vue component

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I need to append m returned data when axios got success but it only appends some part of my code,

## Screenshot

When I click save it supposed to print back my saved data in input fields again with different button for update. but it only prints labels

[image: one]

## Code

`HTML`

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div class="variationData"></div>
  </div>
</template>
```

`script`

```
    export default {
      data() {
            return {
                variationParents: [
                    {
                        name: '',
                        type: ''
                    }
                ],
                variationChilds: [
                    {
                        name: ''
                    }
                ],
              }
     },
     methods: {
        addVariants(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            axios.post('/api/admin/variations/store', {
                childs: this.variationChilds,
                parent: this.variationParents,
            })
            .then(res => {
                console.log(res);
                this.isLoading = false;

                // print back saved data
                $(res.data.data).each(function(_, i){
                    $(i).each(function(__, ii){
                        var row = `<el-col :span="24" style="margin-top:15px;">
                            <el-form-item label="Variation Name">
                                <el-col :span="12" style="margin-top:15px;">
                                    <el-input placeholder="Please input your variation name" value="${i.name}" class="input-with-select"></el-input>
                                    </div>
                                </el-col>

                                <el-col class="line text-center" :span="3">Variation Value(s)</el-col>
                                <el-col :span="9" style="margin-top:15px;">
                                    <el-input value="${ii.name}" placeholder="Please input your variation value" class="input-with-select"></el-input>
                                </el-col>


                                <el-col :span="24" style="margin-top:15px;">
                                    <el-button type="primary" native-type="submit">Update Variations</el-button>
                                </el-col>
                            </el-form-item>
                        </el-col>`;
                        $('.variationData').html(row);
                    });
                });
                //
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log(error);
            })
        },
      },
    }
```

any idea?

## Update

here is how my saved data is returning

[image: one]

and here is what i get based on `Qonvex620` answer

[image: two]

#### Issues

with provided answer of `Qonvex620` i get this issues

1. Only first saved data will append and for second time etc. it
   returns `[Vue warn]: Missing required prop: "value"`
2. I need to loop child elements of saved data in append as well

#### Current code

`HTML`

```
<div class="variationData">
    <template v-for="(item, index) in savedVariations" >
        <div :key="index">
            <el-col :span="12" style="margin-top:15px;">
                <!-- parent -->
                <el-input :value="item.name" placeholder="Please input your variation name" class="input-with-select">
                    <el-select slot="prepend" placeholder="Select">
                        <el-option label="Text" :value="item.type"></el-option>
                        <el-option label="Text Area" :value="item.typerea"></el-option>
                        <el-option label="Boolean" :value="item.typean"></el-option>
                    </el-select>
                </el-input>
            </el-col>

            <el-col class="line text-center" :span="3">Variation Value(s)</el-col>
            <el-col :span="9" style="margin-top:15px;">
                <!-- child's -->
                <el-input :value="item.name" placeholder="Please input your variation value" class="input-with-select">
                </el-input>
            </el-col>
        </div>
    </template>
</div>
```

`Script`

```
data() {
  return {
    savedVariations: [],
  }
},
methods: {
  addVariants(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                axios.post('/api/admin/variations/store', {
                    childs: this.variationChilds,
                    parent: this.variationParents,
                })
                .then(res => {
                    console.log(res);
                    this.isLoading = false;

                    //
                    this.savedVariations= res.data.data
                    //
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    console.log(error);
                })
  },
}
```

## Update 2

I have managed to loop my childs data as well but one issue still remained: if i add second set of data in will override first appended data instead of add below/above it

[image: three]

#### Code

```
<div class="variationData">
    <template v-for="(item, index) in savedVariations" >
        <div :key="index">
            <el-col :span="12" style="margin-top:15px;">
                <!-- parent -->
                <el-input :value="item.name" placeholder="Please input your variation name" class="input-with-select">
                </el-input>
            </el-col>

            <el-col class="line text-center" :span="3">Variation Value(s)</el-col>
            <el-col :span="9" style="margin-top:15px;">
                <template v-for="(itemm, indexx) in item.children" >
                    <div :key="indexx">
                        <!-- child's -->
                        <el-input :value="itemm.name" placeholder="Please input your variation value" class="input-with-select">
                        </el-input>
                    </div>
                </template>
            </el-col>
        </div>
    </template>
</div>
```

**idea?**

#### Update 3 - SOLVED

My remained issue (multiple append "on each time save) solved with this code:

```
.then(res => {
    this.savedVariations.push(res.data.data);
})
```

[image: four]

Comment: where is vue part there ?

Comment: @Qonvex620 this script in in methods

Comment: and your div variationData is also in vue ?

Comment: @Qonvex620 yes they are all in same component, i've updated my code

Comment: Why don't you update your state after the axios call and use that update to render the part you want, instead of using jQuery to do  that? After all that is the whole purpose of libraries like Vue, React, Aurelia, etc. Just my two cents.

Comment: check my answer

Comment: @Rodrigo because it's my first attempt with vue and i'm newbie in it :) feel free to share your way please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare a variable on your data like below

```
data() {
  return {
     rows: []
  }
}
```

now in your axios script you can do this in success return

```
axios.get('/admin/price/fetch_roomtypes').then(res => {
     this.rows= res.data.data
})
```

and in your html like this

```
<div class="variationData">
    <template v-for="(item, index) in row">
       <el-col :span="24" style="margin-top:15px;" :key="index">
           ...
           ...
       </el-col>
    </template>
</div>
```

To loop the variation values of the parent you need to access it, see code below

```
<div class="variationData">
        <template v-for="(item, index) in row">
           <el-col :span="24" style="margin-top:15px;" :key="index">
                <div v-for="values in item.variation_values">   // variations values, just change it using your template you used. just an idea
                       ...
                       ...
                </div>
           </el-col>
        </template>
    </div>
```

so in you case you must structure you data like this code below,

```
data() {
      return {
         variants: [
               {
                  name: '',
                  values: []
               }
         ]
      }
    }
```

now when you append new variation it will like this

```
addVariants() {
   this.variants.push(
      name: 'test'
      values: [5, 10, 3]
  )
```

}

Comment: thanks it's working but has issue as well, `1` it gets my first saved values only `2` it returns this error on second save `[Vue warn]: Missing required prop: "value"`  `3` how do i loop my data child array? `PS:` I will update my question

Comment: check my updated answer, I added. but it's only an idea for you. Not totally what you want

Comment: thanks for the update i already solved it and only 1 issue remained, would you mind check my second update?

Comment: you mean html part?

Comment: Yes, the function when you are adding new value, basically you just push a value inside of the variation values so that it will not make a new loop

Comment: this is screenshot of my adding html https://ibb.co/DLPK0By and function as you know is in my question

Comment: what would be your desired output ?

Comment: `click save -> append 1, click save ->append 2, click save -> append 3` so i would have 3 appended rows including parents and childs of them (explanation with image https://ibb.co/RHyspZf )

Comment: wait what? where this `variants: [{}]` come from? where those `name, values` in push came from? :/

Comment: why if i use `this.savedVariations.push(res.data.data)` then i get broken data? it only shows parent input without value and no inputs for childs :/?

Answer (score 0):

From what I'm seeing, the button is not rendered because you are not using native HTML elements, but custom Vue element (el-col, el-button, el-input, etc). If you want to populate the HTML with custom element, I suggest you rendering the element with v-for as per Qonvex620's answer, or directly use HTML native elements just like below.

```
$(res.data.data).each(function(_, i){
                    $(i).each(function(__, ii){
                        var row = `<div :span="24" style="margin-top:15px;">...
                                    <input placeholder="Please input your variation name" value="${i.name}" class="input-with-select">...
                                    <input value="${ii.name}" placeholder="Please input your variation value" class="input-with-select">


                                ...
                                    <button type="submit">Update Variations</button>...
                            </div>
                        </div>`;
                        $('.variationData').html(row);
                    });
                });
```

But really, rendering the HTML like Qonvex620's answer is much better.  You can maximize Vue's full functionality that way.